# Android Studio 3.0.1 no SDK

Tags: android

After a fresh installation of Android Studio 3.0.1 downloaded via https://developer.android.com/, I am stuck with the following pop-up window

[Pop-up Window asking for the Android SDK Home Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRgor.jpg)

Can anybody help? The link in the screenshot leads to the download site of Androich Studio 3.0.1, getting into deep frustration now.

Answer (score 0):

The default path (after installation) is here:
C:\Users\user(you)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

try it' Maybe help you!

Comment: I saw a comment in another forum, and already checked it. There isn't such a subdirectory. Any way just decided to reinstall the whole thing again.

Comment: AppData is Hide Folder ! press Win + R (open run window) and type appdata and press ok - open app data

Comment: "user(you)" this is your user account name and change with this - for sample : "C:\Users\Xuanfei\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"

Comment: I figured out the problem. It seems like Android Studio took the old settings of the previous version, which is obviously obsolete. Thank you all the same. I did know the folder was hidden by default.